# How to validate version to accept 4.4+ but not 4.4+.0

Tags: regex, semantic-versioning

I have wrote regular expression to accept following type of versions

- "a.*.*"  ---> any version of "a"
- "a.b.*"   ---> any version of "a.b"
- "a.b+"    ---> "a.b" or later
- "a.b.c+"    ---> "a.b.c" or later

An example:  "4.2.2+", "4.3.*, "4.2+"

`/^([0-9])\.([0-9]+[*]{0,1}[+]?)(?:\.([0-9]+[*]{0,1}[+]?))?$/`

It is accepting above all type but also accepting "4.2+.0" which should be invalid. How can I avoid this "4.2+.0" scenario.

Can anyone provide me regex to validate above versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use following regex for validating version
/^\d+((?:.\d+([+]$){0,1})|(.[*]{1,1})){1,2}$/

^ Start of string
\d+ Match 1+ digits

1. (?:.\d+([+]$))+ Repeat matching 1 or more times . and 1+ digits if are you adding + then $ End of string.
   OR
2. (?:.?[*])? Optionally match an optional dot * for one or two times
   $ End of string

[Please check here](https://regex101.com/r/O2xVnI/1)

Answer (score 1):

To match the examples with at least a single dot and an optional `*` or `+` at the end:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?:\.?[+*])?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)+` Repeat matching 1 or more times `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?:\.?[+*])?` Optionally match an optional dot and either `*` or `+`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ahYZII/1).

To also match the examples without a dot you can change the plus to an asterix for the repeating group:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:\.?[+*])?$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0uQJ7E/1).